# Angular 14, component doesn't update when field is changed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following angular component

```
 import {IMessage, EmptyMessage} from ...

  protected Messages: IMessage[] = [];
  protected MessageToSave = emptyMessage; 
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessages();
  }
  ngOnChanges(params: any){
   this.refreshMessages();
}
  getMessages(): void {
    this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.ok && response.body){
          this.Messages = [...response.body]
        }
      }
    );
  }
  refreshMessages(): Observable<boolean>{
    this.messageService.refreshMessages().subscribe(response => {``
      this.Messages = [...response]
      return of(true);
    })
   return of(false);
  }
  saveMessage(){
     
    this.messageService.saveMessage(this.MessageToSave).subscribe(response => {
      if(response.ok){
        this.refreshMessages().subscribe(response => 
        this.MessageToSave = emptyMessage);
      }
    })
  }
}

This is hooked up to a form in the html template, 
<div class="container p-3">
  <div *ngFor="let message of Messages" class="card mb-2">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-top p-3 pb-0">
      <div class="text-secondary small text-truncate">
        <span>{{ message.created_by }} </span>
        <span>{{ message.created_at | date:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}, </span>
        <span>{{ message.created_at | date:'hh:mm' }}</span>
        <span>(Edited {{ getLapsedTime(message.updated_at) }} months ago)</span>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-end">
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pt-0">
      <span>{{message.text}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
form class="pt-2">
    <div class="form-outline mb-3">
      <label for="NewNoteInput" class="form-label">Add New Note</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="noteInput" id="NewNoteInput" [(ngModel)]="MessageToSave.text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary float-end" (click)="saveMessage()" [disabled]="MessageToSave.text.length == 0">Add Note</button>
  </form>
```

I can observe in the network activity tab that SaveMessage and RefreshMessage work as intended, they
get an updated IMessage[] but the component doesn't rerender. How can I solve this?

I was expecteding the component to rerender with  the updated list of Messages when the Messages[] is updated. I also tried to implement ngOnChanges to force a manual update.

Comment: `refreshMessages` returns nothing. Also, return `of(true/false)` inside `subscribe` makses no sense. IDE should pinpoint those issues (especially the first one)

Comment: Get back to the basics and learn how observables work with rxjs. Your code doesn't make much sense. Set up subscription once in ngOnInit and then udpate the rendering whenever you get new data for example.

Comment: Also you have a text template in your subscription. Does it even compile?????